# Alter column length in Schema builder?

Tags: database, schema, builder, laravel, alter

I have two fields i need to increment the character limit on. I're read through the documentation and to my surprise i found no option for it. Is it possible to do? If not, how should i go about solving this?

I could drop the column and re-create it with the correct properties, but i don't want to loose any data in the database.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [Raw Queries](http://laravel.com/docs/database/raw):

```
/**
 * Make changes to the database.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
  DB::query('ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn VARCHAR(new-length)');
}

/**
 * Revert the changes to the database.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
  DB::query('ALTER TABL mytable MODIFY mycolumn VARCHAR(old-length)');
}
```

Replace `mytable`, `mycolumn`, `new-length` and `old-length`.

For Laravel 5+ replace `DB::query` with `DB::statement`.

Comment: In Laravel 5.1, I had to change the DB::query to DB::statement.

Comment: I think it is more acceptable to have SQL commands in upper case and table and column names in lower case.

Answer (score 26):

**For Laravel 4**

```
DB::update('ALTER TABLE `my_table` MODIFY `my_column` VARCHAR(<new length>)');
```

Comment: I'm new at laravel 4... How do I run that update task?

Answer (score 17):

**For Laravel 5:**

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->string('name', 50)->change();
});
```

Check [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#changing-columns) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

Use `` for the column name if the name is a keyword for the system. Otherwise you will get an  "Syntax error or access violation."

```
DB::query("alter table MYTABLE modify `MYCOLUMN` varchar(new-length)");
```